# Why Does the MySQL Query Optimizer choose the secondary index over the clustered primary index?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Why does Mysql optimizer choose the secondary index when doing a 'select * from lookup' with no order by clause.

Is it just a fluke or is this a behind the scenes optimization that assumes since you added a secondary index its more important than the primary key.

I would expect the results to be ordered by primary key as a scan of all the leaf nodes can provide all the data necessary to answer this query.

To reproduce I create a simple key/value pair table (note not auto_increment)

```
create table lookup (
id int not null,
primary key (id),
name varchar(25),
unique k_name (name)
) engine=innodb;
```

Insert some data in random non-alphabetical order

```
insert into lookup values(1, "Zebra"),(2, "Aardvark"),(3, "Fish"),(4,"Dog"),(5,"Cat"),(6,"Mouse");
```

Query the data (this is where I would expect the data to be returned in order of primary key)

```
mysql> select * from lookup;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  2 | Aardvark |
|  5 | Cat      |
|  4 | Dog      |
|  3 | Fish     |
|  6 | Mouse    |
|  1 | Zebra    |
+----+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Where as it is not - it appears that a scan of the k_name leaf nodes has been done. Shown here

```
mysql> explain select * from lookup;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lookup | index | NULL          | k_name | 28      | NULL |    6 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To me this says Mysql is using k_name as a covering index to return the data. If I drop the k_name index then data is returned in primary key order. If I add another un-indexed column data is returned in primary key order.

Some basic information about my setup.

```
mysql> show table status like 'lookup'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: lookup
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 6
 Avg_row_length: 2730
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2011-11-15 10:42:35
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select version();
 +------------+
 | version()  |
 +------------+
 | 5.5.15-log |
 +------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality, the clustered index (aka [**gen_clust_index**](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554)) is populated in an order that has no rhyme or reason other than in rowid order. it is virtually impossible to order the rowids in id order.

In InnoDB, the records in nonclustered indexes (also called secondary indexes) contain the primary key columns for the row that are not in the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.

The secondary index governs order. However, each secondary index entry has a primary key entry to the correct row. Also, think of the covering index scenario you mentioned for k_name.

Now, let's switch gears for a moment and discusss the PRIMARY KEY and k_name:

**QUESTION** : Whose has more columns requested by your original query, the Primary Key or k_name ?

**ANSWER** : k_name, because it has both name and id in it (id being internal because it is the PRIMARY KEY). The covering index k_name fulfills the query better than the primary key.

Now if the query was `SELECT * FROM ORDER BY id`, your EXPLAIN PLAN should look like this:

```
mysql> explain select * from lookup order by id;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lookup | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    6 |       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Without specfiying order, the MySQL Query Optimizer picks the index that best fulfills your query. Of course, k_name has the unfair advantage because

- every column in the table is individually indexed
- every column in the table is a [Candidate Key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/why-do-primary-keys-have-names-of-their-own/1366#1366)
- **k_name IS NOT A SECONDARY INDEX** because it is a Candidate Key just like the PRIMARY KEY.
- user-defined clustered indexes cannot have the row order altered once established

You cannot manipulate the order of the rows at all. Here is proof of that:

```
mysql> alter table lookup order by name;
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 1 warning (0.23 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                           |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1105 | ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered index in the table 'lookup' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table lookup order by id;
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 1 warning (0.19 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                           |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1105 | ORDER BY ignored as there is a user-defined clustered index in the table 'lookup' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: k_name is a secondary index. The definition of Candidate key has nothing to do with indexes. Even a primary key by definition has nothing to do with indexes. Nevertheless - most DBMS automatically create an index for you when you define a primary key.

Comment: k_name IS NOT A SECONDARY INDEX AT ALL. Since it is a Unique Key, it behaves exactly as a PRIMARY KEY does. Unique Keys are, in reality, user-defined clustered indexes. It is just as much a clustered index as a PRIMARY KEY. Even if no primary key exists, a rowid-based gen_clust_index is internally generated. The proof of this lies with InnoDB. You can do ORDER BY primary key columns against MyISAM all day long. In InnoDB, you can neither reorder UNIQUE KEYS nor mitigate ORDER-less SELECT queries in favor of PRIMARY KEY over other UNIQUE KEYS. Secondary Indexes are never unique.

Comment: The clustered index is the one from PRIMARY key. MySQL only uses UNIQUE non-null indexes als clustered index when there is NO primary key. Furthermore only secondary indexes like k_name also include primary key data to reference corresponding rows. You'll see that when you add another column and k_name is not able to provide all data like the clustered index do. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_secondary_index k_name becomes a clustered index when primary key is removed.

Comment: Please notice that the MySQL Query Optimizer chose k_name over PRIMARY KEY because it is internally built the same as the PRIMARY KEY but it better fulfills the query's request. Also note 2 things 1) a secondary index does not have to be UNIQUE, and 2) a UNIQUE index is never viewed by the MySQL Query Optimizer as secondary. As a CAVEAT : Even if you remove UNIQUE from k_name (thus making it Secondary), MySQL Query Optimizer still chooses k_name becauSe all columns from lookup table sits in k_name. PRIMARY KEY only carries id.

Comment: There is exactly one clustered index per InnoDB table. All other indexes (nevertheless they are unique or not) are secondary indexes. When there is a primary key, then this is the clustered index. When there is no prim key then the first non-null unique index will be clustered. When even this is not the case then MySQL uses a hidden clustered index. And it was never point of our discrepancy that the choosen index was choosen because it is a `Covering index` containing all data fullfilling the request. Our discrepancy is about k_name being a secondary index or not.

Comment: I guess I wasn't talking apples to apples. In InnoDB, the clustered index is gen_clust_index (http://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554), which is internal-rowid-based. PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE indexes would then be secondary. In other databases (Oracle, SQL Server) the clustered index is more real because row data occupies a clustered index. No so with InnoDB. I guess this is my discrepancy in hindsight.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. a) The clustered index contains the entire row data in the same page. The primary key only includes the id column (even though the row data is available if it iterated through the leaves) c) k_name is available to use a covering index so this is chosen. Does mysql check to see the size of the record in the cluster page and compare it to size of record in a covering index or will it always prefer the covering index?

Comment: The Covering Index is always the preference of the MySQL Query Optimizer, whether it is in the Clustered Index or Not.

Comment: Thanks Rolando - I accepted your answer and learned some stuff!

Answer (score 2):

It is because InnoDB secondary indexes also include the primary key column. Therefore MySQL is able to fetch all relevant data directly from the secondary index without touching the data rows and therefore it is saving disk IO.

References:

- [Covering Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index)
- [Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)
- [Secondary Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_secondary_index)
- [Clustered Index (aka Index-Organized Table)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_clustered_index)

Comment: The links you supplied better explains the concepts that should be known before designing table and queries than the raw example in my answer. +1 !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well either index is equally efficient in terms of getting the data for that query, so I'm guessing the optimiser just dropped out with a "this'll do"

Add another unique index, it might be as they are all equally efficient, some "FindBestIndex" routine drops out with the last one it read.

It's not the behaviour I'd expect either though if I cared about the order, I'd add an order by id and them let the optimiser choose the primary key instead of going two pass and doing a sort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand the type column. Type column 'index' means a full index scan. When this is the case and if the 'extra' column has 'using index', it means that mysql can get all the data required for the query from index, and needn't resort to the actual table rows. So here the engine, instead of going to the rows (which is costly usually) resorts to use the index which has all the data required by the query. Secondary indexes have the primary key (id, in your case) as the data. That is if you look up a key in the secondary index, you get the primary keys of the table records. Since you just asked for all the values, it's enough to iterate through the secondary index to get what you need.

If the engine chose to iterate over the primary key, the primary keys directly lead to the actual table rows. Mysql tries to avoid that behavior because it's usually inefficient. It's inefficient because usually rows contain more data than contained in the indexes and you potentially have to do more IO.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html